# Modified Bessel function of second kind in GNUPlot

Tags: matlab, gnuplot

I've got to plot the [K-Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-distribution) in GNUPlot and to do so I need the gamma and modified Bessel functions of the second kind in GNUPlot. GNUPlot has a built in gamma function but does not seem to have the modified bessel function of the second kind. If possible I would like the solution it to function as similar to the one found in [MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/besselk.html) as possible. I've tried searching for the solution but as of yet am unable to find it (or a GNUplot version of the bessel function).

If this is the wrong place to ask this please direct me to a more appropriate place.

Comment: No, it is not possible to calculate them directly in `gnuplot`, but you can use any external tool to generate the data file an plot it. `Octave` has e.g. the [besselk function](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Special-Functions.html#doc_002dbesselj). Then do `plot '< octave script.oct'`.

Comment: Thank you kindly. I will do just that!

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to calculate them directly in `gnuplot`, but you can use an external tool to generate the data file and plot it. Use e.g the following script `callbesselk.oct`:

```
# callbesselk.oct start inc stop alpha
#
x_start = str2num(argv(){1});
x_inc = str2num(argv(){2});
x_end = str2num(argv(){3});
alpha = str2num(argv(){4});
x = x_start:x_inc:x_end;
[k, kerr] = besselk(alpha, x);
out = [x; k];
printf("%f %f\n", out);
```

and plot the data with `gnuplot`:

```
plot '< octave -q callbesselk.oct 0 0.01 10 2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Those particular bessel functions aren't available in gnuplot; there are two [patches](http://sourceforge.net/p/gnuplot/patches/search/?q=bessel) to gnuplot which allow you to use functions from an external library.